# How to merge powershell scripts to get disk used space, disk free space, cpu utilization and memory utilization in one csv file?

Tags: powershell

I have a separate code to get the disk space details, how can I merge these two program to get the disk usage, disk free space and cpu utilization so that i will get all the output in one csv file.

```
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName "PhatuggiKaDabba" | 
Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
Select-Object DeviceID, Description,`
    @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
    @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}} |
    Export-CSV 'D:\code\DiskSpaceUsage .csv' -noType
```

I have one more file written in powershell that gives CPU Utilization, Memory Usage and Users

```
    GC D:\ServerList.txt | % {
$Comp = $_
If (Test-Connection $Comp -Quiet){
$Luser = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_process -Filter "Name='Explorer.exe'" -ComputerName $Comp |
% {$_.GetOwner().User} | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ","
$Mem = GWMI -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $COMP
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Server = $Comp
      "CPU usage" = "$((GWMI -ComputerName $COMP win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average) %"
      "Memory usage" = "$("{0:N2}" -f ((($Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $Mem.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize)) %"
      "Total FreeSpace" = "$("{0:N2}" -f ((Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $COMP -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | Measure-Object -property FreeSpace -Sum).Sum /1GB)) GB"
      "logged Users" = $Luser
      }
}
Else{
"" | Select @{N="Server";E={$Comp}},"CPU usage","Memory usage","Total FreeSpace","logged Users"
}
}| Select Server,"CPU usage","Memory usage","Total FreeSpace","logged Users" |
Export-Csv "D:\code\report$(Get-Date -F dd_MM_yyy_hhmm).csv"
```

**Output for both the codes :**

**1.**

```
DeviceID    Description        DiskSize(GB)     FreeSpace(GB)**
C:          Local Fixed Disk   230.21             67.33 
D:          Local Fixed Disk   222.94             79.15
```

**2.**

```
Server    CPU usage  Memory usage   Total FreeSpace logged Users**
Boss'Pc    48%        48.21%           146.48 GB     Boss
```

Comment: You can do that by appending `report$(Get-Date -F dd_MM_yyy_hhmm).csv` to the **DiskSpaceUsage .csv** file and use the -force parameter. But since both the csvs have different number of columns, it wont look pretty.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this, create an array, and load that with custom objects, each of which has the properties you would like to store in the row.

```
$script:array = @()
$computerList |% {
  $ob = New-Object System.Object
  Function1 {
    $ob | Add-Member -type noteProperty -Name CPU -Value $_.cpu
  }
  Function2 {
    $ob | Add-Member -type noteProperty -Name DISKUSE -Value $_.disk
  }
  $script:array += $ob
}
$script:array | Export-CSV file.csv
```

Comment: Just a note: I don't think you need to specify the scope (`script:`) for `$array` in this situation

Comment: @sodawillow I was just doing it to be safe, given I don't know exactly how this could be used. Is that why I've been downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote. But re-reading your answer, your intention with `Function1` and `Function2` is unclear, and I'm pretty sure your syntax is wrong (OR these are declarations lacking the `function` keyword).

Comment: Maybe I should just refrain from using pseudocode-esque answers, but OP had 2 functions and so I supposed the real code could be inferred. I would have copied it over but the formatting makes it hard to read.